# "URI is not registered" when use http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html" in XHTML page

Tags: java, maven, jsf-2, intellij-idea

pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0-m08</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0-m08</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

xhtml file

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
```

web.xml file

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Always "http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html" shown in red colour and it says "URI is not registered".
I need to know, why is it say so and how it fix it. Anyone have any idea?

I am using Intellij IDEA and maven for build project.

Comment: I didn't find the best solution. I used the web.xml code from this tutorial and use in the project. Then, that was working www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_first_application.html

Answer (score -1):

I faced same problems when wrote jsf-based application in Intellij IDEA Community Edition. Only ultimate version has jsf support.

Comment: I have ultimate support. Even I am having problem